# Scroll bar in absolute panel covers (and make inactive) action button

Tags: css, r, shiny, scrollbar, panel

I have a shiny app with an absolute panel in the center of the screen. In this panel I have displayed a long image. Moreover, this panel has an `actionButton()` in the top-right corner to close it.
If, in the `style()` command of the absolute panel, I add the CSS code to insert a vertical scroll-bar, this scroll-bar (even when it's inactive) covers the actionButton and I can't click it anymore. Below a **reprex**:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(

  useShinyjs(),

  absolutePanel(
    id = "image_panel",
    fixed = TRUE,
    top = "5%",
    left = "23%",
    right = "23%",
    bottom = "5%",
    width = "auto",
    height = "70%",
    style = "background-color: lightblue;
             overflow-y: scroll;",

    actionButton(inputId = "close_panel",
                 label = icon(name = "times",
                              lib = "font-awesome"),
                 style = "position: absolute;
                          top: 0;
                          right: 0;
                          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
                          border-width: 0px;
                          padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
                          z-index: 100000;"),

br(),
br(),

    uiOutput(outputId = "image")

  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$close_panel, {

    hideElement(id = "image_panel")

  })

  output$image <- renderUI({

    tags$img(src = "https://tests-images-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/qWgXjZn.png",
             width = "90%")

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To solve that issue I had to set the width of the scroll-bar to zero. But this is not the best solution. The best solution would be to have the scroll bar starting right below the "X" button (in order not to deactivate the button) and it should be visible when scrolling.

Any idea? Thanks for your help!